# en SWIFT cómo enlazar un Tab Bar con un ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

[image: imagen]

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerMenu1: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        title = "Menu1"
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

tengo declarada mi primera vista como ViewControllerMenu1

dudas:

- al mostrar el Navigation Controller y Tab Bar Controller se muestra la primera vista por defecto, y por tanto queda oculta el Tab Bar, quiero que se muestre hasta que elijamos una opción
- una vez que elijamos una opcion quiero que se muestre el botón atras en el navigation, y el tab bar oculto

Comment: Agrega el código de tu respuesta en la pregunta para que no te la cierren porque estás buscando recomendaciones de libros y eso no está permitido.

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer todos los cambios de UI cuando la vista ya se haya dibujado. Por eso debes agregar ese código en el siguiente método:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}
```

De esta manera se mostrará el otro `TabBarController` que tengas en esa vista.

Ahora, para cuando quieras retornar a la vista anterior debes mostrar nuevamente el `tabBarController` que ocultaste y lo haces en este método:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}
```

Comment: Ok, gracias, se va solucionando, no obstante agradecería la documentación para poder aprender, solo conozco el libro de Swift5. La cuestion es que al iniciar la vista antes de pulsar ningún tab ya se oculta el tab bar

Comment: En dónde agregaste el código? El código debes agregar en la vista hija a la cual llamas con el `navigation controller`. Si agregas en la vista principal del `tabBar` es lógico que no te muestre.

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo bien, primero tengo el NC que enlaza al TBC y en cada una de las 5 vistas creo una clase, y se me ocultan, la cuestion es que el TBC muestra por defecto la vista1 y al mostrarse se oculta el TabBar, creo que va a ser difícil de cambiar esto. Por otro lado no se poner el botón atras

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta agregando toda la información, imagen del storyboard para entender el flujo. Sino difícil poder adivinar lo que quieres hacer.